# C++ WinInet Wrapper for Windows Mobile

Tags: windows, mobile, wrapper, wininet

Environment:  Win32, C++/VS2008

I'm getting into the need to make HTTP (*not* HTTPS) requests from the internet using a Windows Mobile phone and to save time + reinventing the wheel, wondered if anybody here might have kindly shared a simple C++ (Win32?) WinInet wrapper or similar class?

The closest I found so far using Google is on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/wininet_wrapper_part1.aspx), but wondered if someone here might yet have a better implementation.

Thank you.   **:)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WinInet API is the same on Windows as it is on Windows CE. And its disgustingly easy to program. Why do you need a c++ wrapper for a really simple C API before you can proceed?

If you need help with WinInet, then ask an actual question.

In the simplest case, use of WinInet would start with InternetOpen, followed by  InternetOpenUrl and InternetReadFile. Making a class to wrap up access to that is really an exercise left for the reader.

Comment: Indeed and you are correct.  The fact is that it got really confusing as I was researching the WinInet stuff and found so many different classes and code samples, to what seemed like, an easy few API calls.  So being new and naive to WinInet, I didn't want to miss anything and so asked for this wrapper that would contain the experience of someone who has used it in the real world already.  Anyhow, I worked it out according to your suggestion and it should be fine.  Thanks.   :)